# How do I complete this proof by induction?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction

*****Prove by induction that $u_n>\frac{1}{2}$ $∀n∈\mathbb{N}$ ; given $u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n^2+1}{u_n+2}$ and $u_1=1$.*****

(Where $\mathbb{N}=${$1,2,3,...$})

Let $P_n$ be the statement to be proved.

The base case is when $n=1$;

$P_1:$  $u_1=1>\frac{1}{2}$

$∴ P_1$ is true.

Now assume that for some n=k;

($P_k$)   $u_k>\frac{1}{2}$  $:k∈ \mathbb {N}$

This is the inductive hypothesis.

Now we aim to prove that;

$u_{k+1}>\frac{1}{2}$

(Given the inductive hypothesis.)

$u_{k+1}=\frac{u_n^2+1}{u_n+2}$

$u_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}=u_k-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{5}{u_k+2}$

Now;

$u_k>\frac{1}{2}$ $\implies \frac{5}{u_k+2}>2$ $∧$ $u_k-\frac{5}{2}>-2$

I set things up so that I could prove that $u_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}>0$ but I don't know what to do after this last step. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Can you show something like $u_{k+1} = \frac12 +\frac{\left(u_k-\frac12\right)^2+\frac12\left(u_k-\frac12\right)}{u_k^{\,}+2}$?

Comment: $u_{k+1}>\frac {\frac 1 2 u_k+1}{u_k+2}=\frac 1  2$.

Comment: There is at least one mistake. If $u_{n + 1} = \frac{u_n^2 + 1}{u_n + 2}$, then it holds that $u_{n + 1} = \frac{u_n}{1 + 2 / u_n} + \frac{1}{u_n + 2}$ and not $u_{n + 1} = u_n - 5 / 2 + \frac{5}{u_n + 2}$

Comment: And so, $u_{n + 1} - 1/2 = \frac{2u_n - 1}{2(1 + 2/u_n)} > 0$ if $u_n > 1/2$.

Comment: Which means that if $u_n > 1/2$ then $u_{n + 1} > 1/2$, i.e. $P(n) \implies P(n + 1)$ with $P(n)$ being the predicate you defined.

Comment: I understand, but isn't the expression I found equivalent to yours? It's weird why it wouldn't work in that form.

Comment: Yes indeed they are equivalent. I didn't spot this. So, I guess the problem is that you need to consider the whole expression $u_n - 5/2 + \frac{5}{u_n + 2} > 0$ and not consider the cases, for instance $\frac{5}{u_n + 2} > 2$, separately.

Comment: For example since you consider the cases separately, when $n = 1$, then $u_n = 1$ which means $\frac{5}{u_n + 2} = 5 / 3 < 2$.

Comment: @prcssngnr See my answer and tell me if it makes sense.

Comment: @prcssngnr I just want to make sure you know that I mean no hostility in my last comment, your input was very helpful and my answer heavily draws from it. (I phrased it kinda awkwardly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the recurrence:

$$ u_{n + 1} = \frac{u_n^2 + 1}{u_n + 2} $$

where $u_1 = 1$ and would like to prove $u_n > \frac{1}{2}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. This is equivalent to proving $u_n - \frac{1}{2} > 0$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. We do so using induction. We first rewrite the recurrence:

$$ u_{n + 1} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{u_{n}^2 + 1}{u_n + 2} - \frac{1}{2} = u_n - \frac{5u_n}{2u_n + 4} $$

Now we assume $u_n - \frac{1}{2} > 0$ and apply induction:

$$ u_{n + 1} - \frac{1}{2} = u_n - \frac{5u_n}{2u_n + 4} > 0 $$
$$ u_n > \frac{5u_n}{2u_n + 4} $$
$$ 1 > \frac{5}{2u_n + 4}$$
$$ 2u_n + 4 > 5$$
$$ u_n - \frac{1}{2} > 0 $$

We have that $u_1 = 1$ so the base case holds and so we conclude $u_n > \frac{1}{2}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You want to prove $u_{k+1}>\frac12$, which is equivalent (Per construction of $u_k$) to $\frac{u_k^2+1}{u_k+2}>\frac12$. But (assuming $u_k+2>0$) this is equivalent to $2(u_k^2+1)>u_k+2$. Knowing that $u_k>\frac12$, can you prove that $2(u_k^2+1)>u_k+2$, and thus prove that $u_{k+1}>\frac12$?

I think the mistake you made is trying to prove that $u_{k+1}-\frac12>0$ instead of $2u_{k+1}>1$.

Comment: I was able to prove it by treating 2(u_k^2+1)>u_k+2 as a quadratic inequality and solving it to show that it is satisfied for u_k>1/2. However, what I would like a lot more to know is why my initial proof fails/ how I could make it work. (The book I'm using basically converts every inequality of this nature to a greater/lesser than 0 inequality, so I would like to stick with one method for proving these recurrence inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got it. I didn't make a mistake but it seems it was too early to use the inductive hypothesis. Using it after adding the two fractions completes the inductive step;

$u_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}=u_k-\frac{5u_k}{2u_k+4}$

and since $u_k>\frac{1}{2}\implies \frac{5u_k}{2u_k+4}>\frac{1}{2}$, subtracting this from the inductive hypothesis proves that $u_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}>0$

Edit: Subtracting inequalities like this is invalid. Instead, a correct approach is in the comments to this answer by prcssngnr.

Comment: Actually, what needs to be done is to check if $u_{k + 1} - 1/2 > 0$, i.e. that $u_k - \frac{5u_k}{2u_k + 4} > 0$, which is equivalent to checking that $1 > \frac{5}{2u_k + 4}$. The last inequality holds if $u_k > 1/2$. So instead of $u_k > 1/2 \implies \frac{5u_k}{2u_k + 4} > 1/2$, the implication needs to be $u_k > 1/2 \implies \frac{5}{2u_k + 4} < 1$.

Comment: If the implication holds, then by induction the inequality holds for all naturals $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Wouldn't the inductive hypothesis mean that $\frac{5u_k}{2u_k+4}>\frac{1}{2}$ since $u_k$ needs to be greater than 1/2 meaning that the lowest the above fraction could be is a number greater than 1/2? (substituting $u_k=\frac{1}{2}$ into $\frac{5u_k}{2u_k+4}$ should give the largest value it cannot be no?)

Comment: We are trying to prove that $u_k > 1/2$ for all naturals $k$. Equivalently, we can prove that $u_k - 1/2 > 0$ for all naturals $k$. In this latter case we show that $u_k - \frac{5u_k}{2u_k + 4} > 0$, which implies $1 > \frac{5}{2u_k + 4}$, holds for all naturals using induction from which we conclude that $u_k > 1/2$ for all naturals $k$.

Comment: The induction hypothesis is that $u_n > 1/2$ for all naturals $n$. We are given that $u_{n + 1} = \frac{u_n^2 + 1}{u_n + 2}$ and apply this fact in the inductive step. The inductive step being that $u_n - \frac{5u_n}{2u_n + 4} > 0$. Which holds since according to the induction hypothesis $u_n > 1/2$. And so we conclude $u_{n + 1} > 1/2$.

Comment: @prcssngnr I know it's been a long while but today I revisited this question and realised my answer wasn't correct. Yours is so if you'd like to post it as an answer rather than a comment I'll accept it.

Comment: I've posted an answer to your question based on the comments.